# Trying to make a game where i dodge meteorites falling from the sky. as3

Tags: actionscript-3

im trying to make a game where meteorites are falling from the sky... so far I have got 1 falling and dissapearing but it isnt looping. How do i make multiple meteorites come down at different locations and keep looping this is my code so far

```
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 400;

test_mc.x = randomX;
test_mc.y = 0;

var speed:Number = 10;

test_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);

function moveDown(e:Event):void
{
  e.target.y += speed; 

  if(e.target.y >= 500
  )
  {
    test_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having one test_mc object, define an Array and a counter variable to track when a new Meteorite should be added:

```
var meteorites:Array = new Array();
var counter:int = 0;
```

Instead of adding the event listener to a single meteorite add the event listener to the stage and have it trigger your game loop:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);  

function gameLoop(e:Event):void {
    counter ++;
    if (counter>=10) { // this will add a new Meteorite every 10 frames
        counter = 0;
        meteorites.push(new Meteorite());
        addChild(meteorites[meteorites.length-1]);
        // you could add code here to position the new Meteorite (meteorites[meteorites.length-1]) randomly in the X direction
    }
    if (meteorites.length>0) {
        for (var loop:int=meteorites.length-1;loop>=0;loop--) {
            meteorites[loop].y += speed;
            if (meteorites[loop].y>500) {
                removeChild(meteorites[loop]);
                meteorites.splice(loop, 1) // this removes the meteorite at index [loop] from the Array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work you will have to enable your meteorite MovieClip for actionscript (in the Library properties/advanced panel) and give it a Class name of Meteorite.

**EDIT**
I've added in 'addChild' and 'removeChild' calls which will be necessary to display your meteorites. Also you will not need any meteorites positioned on your stage in Flash. This code will add them in-game for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use array or vector (which is better) (or even you can make your own linked list class, or loop throug children of stage/sprite) to access all your existing meteorites. Loop throug array/vector/list in every frame to make them move and handle collisions. Count frames or use Math.random() to make pause before new meteorite will appear.

Comment: Also you can make "smart" meteorite class which will move itself and destroy itself when it's y>= 500. Just make them from time to time and put on stage/sprite whatever.